# Как повесить второе событие на ссылку в Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Привет. Есть ссылка и на нее уже повешено событие которое добавляет товар в корзину, нужно чтобы помимо добавления в корзину выполнялся вызов модального окна, вызывается у меня так: `class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-16"`.

Как добавить в ссылку вызов второго события?

Код ссылки ниже:

```
<a href="#" onclick="submitaction('{{url('catalog/order/add')}}')">
    <p>
        ADD TO CART
    </p>
</a>
```

Comment: ну так и добавьте этот класс и атрибут ссылке

Comment: Делаю так, но модальное окно не срабатывает, вывоз модального окна рабочий.

<a href="#" class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-16" onclick="submitaction('{{url('catalog/order/add')}}')">

Comment: :-D что значит вызов модального окна? :) это ж просто класс и атрибут.

Comment: Приведите рабочий пример вашего кода в котором воспроизводится проблема

Comment: Для добавления нескольких обработчиков события используйте [addEventListener](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#addeventlistener-и-removeeventlistener).

Comment: @w3lifer, раньше был комментарий, что используется какая-то библиотека для модальных окон, она по умолчанию и должна обработчики сама добавлять

Answer (score 1):

Ну если говорить о правильном решении, лучше создать отдельный метод, в котором вы будите вызывать метод "submitaction" с нужными параметрами, а затем вызывать метод открытия модального окна. 
Пример:

```
function myFunc (url) {
   submitaction('{{url('+url+')}}');
   // дальше метод вызова модального окна вида
   // $('#someModal').modal({...props}); - пример для jquery
}
```

А уже функцию "myFunc" ставите на событие `onClick="myFunc(url /*...props*/)"`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `addEventListener`, на ссылку можно вешать, как разные события с разными функциями, так и множество функций на одно событие.

Если используете событие `click` на ссылке, не забудьте в обработчике отменить ее действие на событие click по умолчанию, методом `preventDefault()`.

```js
var magicLink=document.getElementById("magiclink");
magicLink.addEventListener("click",function(e){e.preventDefault();alert("Я сработал первым!");},false);
magicLink.addEventListener("click",function(e){e.preventDefault();alert("А я вторым!");},false);
magicLink.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){alert("Вернись!")},false);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="magiclink">Text</a>
```